# How do I clear my UITextField's text when I tap on it again?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` called `numberToAdd` and it asks the user to enter a number to be added to 10 and a `UIButton` that calculates it. Then there's a `UILabel` that displays the sum.

Say I enter a number 5 into the `UITextField` and press calculate, the `UILabel` will show 15.

How do I write a code that will clear the `UITextField` when I tap on it again instead of having to delete the number 5 manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think in three solutions for your problem:

**Option 1**
Clear the TextField everytime you touch it

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == self.numberToAdd) {
        self.numberToAdd1.text = @"";
    }
}
```

**Option 2**
Clear the `TextField` when you touch it, only if you already calculated the number.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL calculateDone;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.calculateDone = false;
}

- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

    //sum label number and textField number
    int sum = [self.label.text intValue] + [self.numberToAdd.text intValue];
    //set label
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];

    // sum done true
    self.calculateDone = true;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == self.numberToAdd)
    {
        if (self.calculateDone)
        {
            self.numberToAdd.text = @"";
            self.calculateDone = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 3**
Clear the `TextField` when you click calculate button

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

    //sum label number and textField number
    int sum = [self.label.text intValue] + [self.numberToAdd.text intValue];
    //set label
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];

    //reset textField
    self.numberToAdd.text = @"";

}
```

You can also check the text entered in the `TextField`, because you only wants numbers in the `TextField`, right?.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlRegEx;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPredicate *urlRegExTest;

//This Regex accepts negative and positive numbers
self.urlRegEx = @"((-)?[0-9]*)";
self.urlRegExTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", self.urlRegEx];


- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

    // if text is a valid Number
    if ([self.urlRegExTest evaluateWithObject:self.numberToAdd.text]) {

        int sum = [self.label.text intValue] + [self.numberToAdd.text intValue];
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];
    }

}
```

You can [download an example code here](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/clearUITextField).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should have a flag which indicate number is calculated or not, after user tapping calculate button, you should turn on that flag, then when user taps the `TextField` again, you can use `UITextFieldDelegate` detect the action and clear the `textfield` as below answer:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
    if (isCalculated) {  
        textField.text = @""; 
        isCalculated = NO;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer to get clear text on TextField.First you should use BOOL flag for know if it calculated or not let say BOOL flag is isCal.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *clearTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(clearTextField:)];

 [self.textView addGestureRecognizer:clearTapRecognizer];
```

and in clearTextField method write belove code.

```
- (void)clearTextField:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
     if(isCal)
     {
        UITextView *_textView = (UITextView*) gestureRecognizer.view;
        _textView.text=@"";
        isCal=NO;
     }
}
```